# Reduce app memory footprint

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiimage, uipageviewcontroller

I have a very image heavy app. (And before you say: no I can't reduce the amount of images). This means that there are a lot of `UIImageView`s going on in my storyboard files.

The overall structure of the app is something like this:

[image]

The `Content View Controller` is the one that is image heavy and at any one time up to around 12 of them can be in memory at any one time due to the page view controller.

I have been getting memory warnings and leaks (from my investigations these are separate unrelated events) and the system has terminated the app on occasion.

Aside from writing my own implementation of `UIPageViewController` what can I do to reduce memory footprint?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to create you own implementation of `UIPageViewController`, you just need to use `UIPageViewControllerDelegate/DataSource` and `UIViewController` wisely.
 For instance `UIViewController` has a method that is triggered during memory warnings, are you getting rid of heavy images on VCs that are not visible inside that method?

Comment: No not yet. I have started by releasing view controllers managed by `UITableView` as soon as they're no longer visible. So there should only be max 4 view controllers in memory at any one time.

Comment: Also. How best to tell if a view controller is visible when a memory warning is triggered? And if i remove all the heavy images will they be reloaded when the controller next becomes visible?

Comment: Check also if you images are cached or retained somewhere. If your are loading them using UIImage(named:) they will be cached and the system should release them after a memory warning.

Comment: Usually you check if the view controller's view has a superview, but with page vc is more complicated since dei can be loaded offscreen. Images will be reloaded if you apply the correct business logic, probably now you are loading them in viewDidLoad that will be called one time, try in viewDidAppear or viewWiilAppear

Comment: They are simply being decoded by the UIStoryboard class. `initWithDecoder:`

Comment: I think it's something to do with the system `UIImage` cache. It seems to hit the boundary and then flush the cache and then hit the boundary again.